# code: "ER_PARSE_ERROR", errno: 1064, mySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am getting the following error when trying to insert multiple inserts based on one form

"sql: "INSERT INTO ( pokemon (pokemonname) VALUES ('sadfasd'), INSERT INTO location (locationname) VALUES ('asdfasdf'), INSERT INTO primarymove (primarymovename) VALUES ('asdf'), INSERT INTO type (typename) VALUES ('2'))"

sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '( pokemon (pokemonname) VALUES ('sadfasd'), INSERT INTO location (locationname) ' at line 1","

And below is my post request

```
   router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var mysql = req.app.get('mysql');
    var sql = "INSERT INTO pokemon (pokemonname) VALUES (?), INSERT INTO location (locationname) VALUES (?), INSERT INTO primarymove (primarymovename) VALUES (?), INSERT INTO type (typename) VALUES (?)";
    var inserts = [req.body.pokemonname, req.body.locationname, req.body.primarymovename, req.body.typename];
    sql = mysql.pool.query(sql, inserts, function(error, results, fields){
            if(error){
                    res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
                    res.end();
            } else{
                    res.redirect('/pokemon');
             }
    });
```

});

I am going to assume it has to do with my multiple INSERT INTO requests, I am basically trying to do multiple insert statements going to various different tables. Or is it not possible?

Comment: The comma is not used to separate statements

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace commas with ';'

Comment: Thank you - I updated with ; but still getting the error